# div centralized animate.css

Tags: css, animation, animate.css

All right?

I'm having a little problem to centralize DIV I'm for generating a warning, I noticed that the animation is what I use being the problem, but can not figure out how to fix this.

```css
html, body{
  background-color: #DDD;
}
#aviso {
 text-align: center;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: black;
 padding: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 opacity: 0.95;
 -moz-opacity: 0.90;
 filter: alpha(opacity=90);
 top: 20%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, 0);
 z-index: 999;
 display: block; 
  -vendor-animation-duration: 6s;
  -vendor-animation-delay: 6s;
  -vendor-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
#aviso p{
    color: white;
}
#aviso i{
    font-size: 70px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css">

<div id="aviso" class="animated slideOutDown" onclick="">
    <p><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></p>
    <p>Campos obrigatórios não foram preenchidos</p>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/KaeDesign/pen/GJNPZW

Could someone give me a hand? Note that without the Animate.css it is usually centered.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain more of what you are wanting to accomplish?

Comment: use `#aviso {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }`, or use `body:{text-align:center}` and `#aviso {display:inline-block}`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Already managed to solve :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want the notice to slide down and then stay right?
If that is the case, do the following:

1) Use the class "slideInDown" rather than "slideOutDown" 
2) Wrap the #aviso with a .container element with position: relative
3) Give #aviso absolute position with margin: 10% auto; 
4) Nix animation-related css

so the html would look like:

```
<div class="container" style="position:absolute">
    <div id="#aviso">some stuff</div>
</div>
```

with the element #aviso looking like:

```
#aviso {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10% auto;
  width: 400px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0.95;
  -moz-opacity: 0.90;
  filter: alpha(opacity=90);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
}
```

Working Example: http://codepen.io/JordanLittell/pen/KpNbyr

Comment: Perfect! I racked my brain here with some adjustments so that it could work that way, I did not want to use the 'position: absolute;' but it was the best way. Thank you very much for your help.